# Jenkins Multipipeline Project with Groovy Pipeline Script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins Multi - pipeline project to deploy multiple projects with the same template script .
And each project runs on a SCM trigger after branch indexing.
I need make an exception for a particular branch that it triggers with two types of reasons 
1. with SCM trigger
2. Periodic Trigger

How can i achieve it without a change in the branch that has the jenkins file

Answer (score 1):

You could run a cron job external to Jenkins that triggers "build now" on a particular branch, using the same link for "build now" that you would use in the web UI.

Comment: But is it possible with the Multipipeline project?

Comment: Sure, here's what the link structure looks like for building a particular branch in a multi-pipeline: /example.com/job/your-pipeline-name/job/your-branch-name/build?delay=0sec

Comment: that said I will be able to post a Build parameter as well to the specific job I guess :-)